# Bind MetaL in icewm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, icewm

Anybody managed to bind the Windows key in IceWM ? It seems I can't bind it to anything since I disabled the "treat as Ctrl+Alt" option.

```
#  Treat Super/Win modifier as Ctrl+Alt
# ModSuperIsCtrlAlt=1 # 0/1
ModSuperIsCtrlAlt=0 # 0/1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the key's name is "Super".

```
key "Super+k"       konsole
key "Super+f"       firefox
key "Super+e"       emacs -fg white -bg black -cr honeydew2
key "Super+g"       gimp
key "Super+l"       libreoffice
key "Super+Shift+k"     konversation
key "Super+r"       killall -SIGHUP icewm
key "Super+Shift+Ctrl+k"    krdc
key "Super+v"       vlc
```

I particularly like Super+r

Answer (score 1):

For me works in /.icewm/keys this (simply add to keys your keyboard layout):

key "Super+i"               setxkbmap -layout it

key "Super+s"               setxkbmap -layout sk

key "Super+e"               setxkbmap -layout latam